# Unity Decorator Extension fails with multiple implementations

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, dependency-injection, unity-container, decorator

I've been struggling with this problem for a couple days, and I still am not sure how to solve it.

I've created a container extension for the Unity Container to enable me to easily register decorator classes in the container. This is the implementation I currently have, which is almost identical to the one in [this](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Decorator-Unity-Container-Extension.aspx) article:

```
public class DecoratorExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    private int m_order;
    private Dictionary<Type, IList<DecoratorRegistration>> m_typeStacks;

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        m_typeStacks = new Dictionary<Type, IList<DecoratorRegistration>>();
        Context.Registering += AddRegistration;
        Context.Strategies.Add(new DecoratorBuildStrategy(m_typeStacks), UnityBuildStage.PreCreation);
    }

    private void AddRegistration(object _sender, RegisterEventArgs _e)
    {
        if (_e.TypeFrom == null || !_e.TypeFrom.IsInterface)
            return;

        GetStack(_e.TypeFrom)
            .Add(new DecoratorRegistration {Order = m_order++, Type = _e.TypeTo});
    }

    private IList<DecoratorRegistration> GetStack(Type _type)
    {
        if (!m_typeStacks.ContainsKey(_type))
            m_typeStacks.Add(_type, new List<DecoratorRegistration>());

        return m_typeStacks[_type];
    }
}
```

What this does is use a list for each type, to store all type registrations for the same target type, so that I can reassemble it when Resolve is called, using this build strategy:

```
internal class DecoratorBuildStrategy : BuilderStrategy
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IList<DecoratorRegistration>> m_typeStacks;

    internal DecoratorBuildStrategy(Dictionary<Type, IList<DecoratorRegistration>> _typeStacks)
    {
        m_typeStacks = _typeStacks;
    }

    public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext _context)
    {
        var key = _context.OriginalBuildKey;
        if (_context.GetOverriddenResolver(key.Type) != null)
            return;

        // Only interfaces can use decorators.
        if (!key.Type.IsInterface)
            return;
        
        // Gets the list of types required to build the 'decorated' instance.
        // The list is reversed so that the least dependent types are built first.
        var decoratorTypes = GetDecoratorTypes(key.Type).Reverse().ToList();
        if (!decoratorTypes.Any())
            return;

        object value = null;
        foreach (var type in decoratorTypes)
        {
            Type typeToBuild = type;
            if (typeToBuild.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            {
                Type[] genericArgumentTypes = key.Type.GetGenericArguments();
                typeToBuild = typeToBuild.MakeGenericType(genericArgumentTypes);
            }

            value = _context.NewBuildUp(new NamedTypeBuildKey(typeToBuild, key.Name));

            // An Override is created so that in the next BuildUp the already 
            // built object gets used instead of doing the BuildUp again and 
            // entering an infinite loop
            _context.AddResolverOverrides(new DependencyOverride(key.Type, value));
        }

        _context.Existing = value;
        _context.BuildComplete = true;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Type> GetDecoratorTypes(Type _type)
    {
        var typeList = m_typeStacks.GetValueOrDefault(_type) ?? new List<DecoratorRegistration>(0);
        if (!_type.IsGenericType)
            return typeList.Select(_reg => _reg.Type);

        // If the type is a generic type, we need to get all open generic registrations
        // alongside the closed ones
        var openGenericList = m_typeStacks
                .GetValueOrDefault(_type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) ?? 
                new List<DecoratorRegistration>(0);

        // The final result is an ordered concatenation of the closed and open registrations 
        // that should be used for the type
        return typeList
            .Concat(openGenericList)
            .OrderBy(_registration => _registration.Order)
            .Select(_reg => _reg.Type);
    }
}
```

This is where the DecoratorRegistration model is used. It is just a pair of type/int that represents the order of the registration. I created this to be able to mix open and closed generic registrations correctly:

```
internal struct DecoratorRegistration
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

This works wonders for the most part. The problem started when I had a class that implemented two interfaces, one which was decorated, and one that wasn't.

This is the current test case I'm trying to make work:

```
private interface IAny<T> {}
private interface IAnotherInterface {}
private class Base<T> : IAnotherInterface, IAny<T> {}   
private class Decorator1<T> : IAny<T>
{
    internal readonly IAny<T> Decorated;

    public Decorator1(IAny<T> _decorated)
    {
        Decorated = _decorated;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void DecoratorExtensionDoesNotInterfereWithNormalRegistrations()
{
    // Arrange
    var container = new UnityContainer()
        .AddNewExtension<DecoratorExtension>()
        .RegisterType<Base<string>>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
        .RegisterType<IAny<string>, Decorator1<string>>()
        .RegisterType<IAny<string>, Base<string>>()
        .RegisterType<IAnotherInterface, Base<string>>();

    // Act
    var decorated = container.Resolve<IAny<string>>();
    var normal = container.Resolve<IAnotherInterface>();
    var anotherDecorated = container.Resolve<IAny<string>>();
    var anotherNormal = container.Resolve<IAnotherInterface>();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(normal, typeof (IAnotherInterface));
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(decorated, typeof (Decorator1<string>));
    Assert.AreSame(normal, anotherNormal);
    Assert.AreSame(decorated, anotherDecorated);
}
```

This test should make my intent clear. I wanted singleton classes, but the first call to Resolve, for either `IAnotherInterface` or `IAny<string>` results in every subsequent call to return the same thing. Thus, I get an exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Decorator1`1[System.String]' to type 'IAnotherInterface'.
```

on this line:

```
    var normal = container.Resolve<IAnotherInterface>();
```

I'm not sure what to do here. I had to temporarily disable singletons in our project so that this could work as intended. What I wanted is that the `Base<string>` instance was a sintleton, but when I requested a `IAny<string>` it would create a NEW instance with the SAME base being decorated.

This is still using .Net 4.0, so I'm stuck with Unity 2.1 here (shouldn't matter in this case though).

Comment: Have you considered switching to a different framework?

Comment: @Steven Hey there Steven, I actually expected a comment from you and you didn't disappoint xD. Yeah, I'm aware that some containers have support for this out of the box, like Windsor or your Simple Injector, but we have a very big project here, and some things are tied to the container in places (where injection is not natively supported like webforms and stuff), so I will only go down that route if it is completely impossible to make this work. I could for instance split the implementations in multiple classes, but this a last resort solution since it will affect the code base significantly.

Comment: @Steven One other reason is that we also have a custom designed Enterprise Library application block. It was actually created before we started using IoC, and it is extremely easy to integrate it with unity (there is an already implemented extension that loads application blocks automatically in the container). I would have to implement the adapter logic to integrate that with other containers. It's not that hard to do that actually, just another aspect that complicates things a little.

Comment: I’m glad I’m living up to your expectations :-) I don't think Windsor's support for decorators is any better than Unity's. Autofac has much better support, but when it comes to applying generic decorators, Simple Injector is the king here. It natively understands generic type constraints and easily allows you to apply decorators conditionally based on static type information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've solved this, so I figured that it would be good to replicate the answer I got from Randy Levy from the EntLib team here.

It basically boils down to the build key I was using to register the decorator instance. With my code, the instance was actually registered with the base class type, while I needed to register it with the actual decorator type.

[This post](https://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/449159) has the suggested workaround for the issue, which worked very nicely on our end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for, but I think this does the trick in the specific case in your test:

```cs
container.RegisterType<IAny<string>, Base<string>>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), "Inner");

container.RegisterType<IAny<string>, Decorator1<string>>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter(typeof(IAny<string>), "Inner")));

container.Register<IAnotherInterface>(new InjectionFactory(
    c => c.Resolve<IAny<string>>("Inner")));
```

You don't need that extension for that.

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to do decorators on Unity out of the box, but obviously this is a hassle. I currently have 5 chained decorators on a class. The code to register that would be absurdly unreadable and very hard to maintain. There is the other problem of having to know each constructor, which again has maintenance problems. I think in my case here I would consider this the absolutely last solution to this problem :(. Considering what I asked in the question though, it is a completely valid answer.