# Unity Container - wrap all resolved implementations of parent interface

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I would like to be able to use Unity Container to, in addition to resolving interfaces, wrap all instances that implement a common parent interface. For example, say that you have common interfaces defined for commands and the implementations of classes that handle them:

```
public interface ICommand {}

public interface ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
{
    void Execute(T command);
}
```

You then have some classes that implement these interfaces:

```
public class MoveCommand : ICommand { /* properties */ }

public class MoveHandler : ICommandHandler<MoveCommand>
{
    public void Execute(MoveCommand command) { /* do stuff */ }
}

public class CreateCommand : ICommand { /* properties */ }

public class CreateHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateCommand>
{
    public void Execute(CreateCommand command) { /* do other stuff */ }
}
```

These commands are then registered with Unity Container:

```
container.RegisterType<ICommandHandler<MoveCommand>, MoveHandler>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ICommandHandler<CreateCommand>, CreateHandler>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Now, say that you have some interfaces for implementing cross-cutting concerns:

```
public interface ILogger<T> : ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand { }

public class Logger<T> : ILogger<T> where T : ICommand
{
    private ICommandHandler<T> handler;

    public Logger(ICommandHandler<T> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void Execute(T command)
    {
        // Log stuff
        handler.Execute(command);
    }        
}
```

Registered in Unity like so:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

I would like to be able to have Unity wrap every ICommandHandler in an ILogger when resolving it. One way would be to modify the RegisterType call for each ICommandHandler type. However, in the spirit of "Don't Repeat Yourself", I would really like to be able to specify once that *all* ICommandHandler types should additionally be wrapped in an ILogger of the appropriate type. There may be a large number of ICommandHandler types being registered, as well as additional wrappers for things like error handling, authentication, and whatnot, so the repetition and opportunities for oversights would be great. Is there a way to apply the wrapper to all of them at once?

Edit: Here is the syntax that I was looking for, adapted from the accepted answer and the first link in the accepted answer:

```
container.RegisterType<ICommandHandler<MoveCommand>, MoveHandler>("InnerCommand", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ICommandHandler<CreateCommand>, CreateHandler>("InnerCommand", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(Logger<>),
    InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), "InnerCommand")));
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to do Aspect Orientated Programming. Have a look at PostSharp https://www.postsharp.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Logger<T>` seems like it is a decorator, but it is weird construct, and I don't advice letting it derive from `ICommandHandler<T>`. There is no reason to do this and it complicates your design. I suggest the following:

```
public interface ILogger {
    void Log(LogEntry entry);
}

public class FileLogger : ILogger { ... }
```

Now you can simply inject `ILogger` into classes that need to log. In case you want to apply logging to all command handlers in the system, you can define a decorator for this:

```
public class LoggingCommandHandlerDecorator<T> 
    : ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
{
    private ILogger logger;
    private ICommandHandler<T> decoratee;

    public LoggingCommandHandlerDecorator(ILogger logger, ICommandHandler<T> decoratee)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
    }

    public void Execute(T command)
    {
        // Log stuff
        this.logger.Log("Executing " + typeof(T).Name + " " +
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command));

        decoratee.Execute(command);
    }        
}
```

Note that this decorator depends on `ILogger`. It allows applying logging to command handlers.

There are other answers on Stackoverflow that show how to register generic decorators, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813630/how-to-do-open-generic-decorator-chaining-with-unity-unityautoregistration) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478689/unity-decorator-extension-fails-with-multiple-implementations).

I advice against using interception, because the use of decorators leads to much cleaner and more maintainable design.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Unity interception behavior. You need to do the following:

1) Obtain the Unity.Interception NuGet Package.

2) Instruct the unity container to use the interception extension like this:

```
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
```

3) Create your interception behavior like this:

```
public class LoggingBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
{
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        var next_bahavior = getNext();

        //Here do your logging before executing the method

        var method_return = next_bahavior.Invoke(input, getNext);

        //Here do your logging after executing the method

        return method_return;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
    {
        yield break;
    }

    public bool WillExecute
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

And put the required code to actually do the logging inside it. Please note that my sample behavior has no constructor. In case you need to inject something in it you need to either register it (the dependency) with the container. Or you can manually create the behavior yourself and register it as an instance with the unity container.

Please note that you can use the "input" variable to obtain the method invocation arguments. Also you can use the method_return variable to obtain the return value and the thrown exception if any.

4) When you register your types, instruct unity to use the interception behavior we just defined like this:

```
container.RegisterType<ICommandHandler<MoveCommand>, MoveHandler>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingBehavior>());
container.RegisterType<ICommandHandler<CreateCommand>, CreateHandler>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingBehavior>());
```

Now you don't need the ILogger and the Logger types that you described.

Comment: Unity interception is a great way to handle this. It also allows you to intercept any/all classes, not just ones that implement a specific interface.

Comment: The main point of my question was to be able to apply the logging behavior once to ICommandHandler, rather than once for each closed ICommandHandler type. I don't see how this answer helps on that front.

Comment: You are already registering every closed ICommandHandler implementation, right? In this case, what is the problem with specifying the interceptor for each one of them?

Comment: From my perspective, changing the logging implementation from one class to another should involve a change to a single line of code. Using the method described in the edit, changing the logging implementation is simple and there is no possibility of missing any handlers when making the change.

Comment: Here also you can change the logger implementation easily, everything related to logging is done here in the `LoggingBehavior ` class. You can also inject some `ILogger` in the class and have multiple implementations of `ILogger`. Please note that my solution is more generic since it is not specific only to `ICommandHandler<>`. It can be used to create logging for any class/interface. Having said that, I really don't like using DI container based interception. I am just proposing this since you are already using the DI container.